# multiprocessing и передача в него аргументов

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, multiprocessing

Есть код:

```
username = 'ivan'
parted_list = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]]
my_function(username,parted_list):
    print('yep!')
p = multiprocessing.Pool()
thread_number = 0
for i in range(10):
    work = p.map(lambda f: f(username,parted_list[thread_number]),[my_function])
    thread_number +=1
p.close()
p.join()
```

в чем проблема: код работает, но потоки запускаются по очереди, ввиду цикла for. Чтобы они запустились параллельно, как я понимаю надо вот эту строку:

```
work = p.map(lambda f: f(username,parted_list[thread_number]),[my_function])
```

переделать на эту:

```
work = p.map(lambda f: f(username,parted_list[thread_number]),[my_function,my_function,my_function,my_function,my_function,my_function,my_function,my_function,my_function,my_function])
```

и убрать цикл `for`.
НО! для каждой функции должен быть разный `thread_number`, что без цикла получить- я не знаю как. Есть решение этой проблемы? Желательно еще в дзене Python, чтобы не писать `my_function` 10 раз, а сделать это более лаконично.

Answer (score 0):

Использовать `Process` и `daemon=True` [Документация по этому](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.daemon)
Вот пример Вашего кода:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep


def my_function(username, parted_list):
    print('yep!', username, parted_list)
    sleep(10)
    print(parted_list, 'outed')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tmp = []
    thread_number = 0

    username = 'ivan'
    parted_list = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5],
                   [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]]

    for i in range(10):
        p = Process(
            group=None,
            target=my_function,
            args=(username, parted_list[thread_number],),
            daemon=True
        )
        tmp.append(p)
        thread_number += 1

    for item in tmp:
        item.start()

    for item in tmp:
        item.join()
```

Вывод:

```
yep! ivan [1]
yep! ivan [2]
yep! ivan [4]
yep! ivan [5]
yep! ivan [10]
yep! ivan [6]
yep! ivan [7]
yep! ivan [9]
yep! ivan [3]
yep! ivan [8]
[2] outed
[1] outed
[4] outed
[5] outed
[10] outed
[6] outed
[7] outed
[9] outed
[3] outed
[8] outed
```